# How to generate url in twig passing parameters?

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, get, twig

Maybe this is a stupid question but I spent a lot of time trying to make it working...

This is from my routing file:

```
search:
  path: /search
  defaults: { _controller: MyAppBundle:Default:search}
```

My twig template:

```
{{ path('search', {'value': value}) }}
```

And my controller:

```
public function searchAction(Request $request){
        $value = $request->query->get('value');
```

My problem is the following, with the above data I am generating this url:

```
/search/value
```

instead of the url which I want:

```
/search?value=value
```

I prefer clean urls, but I need to pass the values in the url using "?" due to that I need to pass different values in the url and some of them can be omitted in different circumstances

Comment: See my EDIT #2 comments.

Comment: it must work ! if you pass a parametre to path in twig without adding this parameter to the routing it will show you the variable in the url without clean url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you face this issue, please check that you aren't passing your parameters in your routing file and also check that you haven't a form in your html with post as method (if you have any form with post method, changing it to get will solve the issue)

Answer (score 1):

Why not do this instead:

```
search:
  path: /search/{value}
  defaults: { _controller: MyAppBundle:Default:search}
```

---

```
public function searchAction(Request $request, $value){
        // Do something with $value...
```

It doesn't address the URL issue, but you can easily set the value parameter in your Twig file, and this is the standard way to do it in Symfony.

---

EDIT #2 - based on comment.

What I do is something like this:

```
{{ path('searchPet',{'petID': pet.getPetId}) }}
```

In the above case, `searchPet` is the route, `petID` is the parameter name, and `pet.getPetId` is my `pet` method; where `pet` is a Petition Entitiy that I've passed in to the Controller (which Twig renders); So I'm calling `getPetId()` which returns the Id of the Petition.

So if you render in Controller like this with `param` being the variable:

```
return $this->render('search.html.twig', array(
                'param' => 'test',
                ...
            ));
```

Then in Twig do this:

```
{{ path('search', {'value': param}) }}
```

Then URL will be in this case: `/search/test`

---

EDIT #3 - based on last comment.

Quote the value you want to send, so you want to send 'test', do this:

```
{{ path('search', {'value': 'test'}) }}
```

I tested this - it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I always configure the routing in that way but as you say that doesn't address the URL issue. How can set the value parameter in twig? I know that I can create the url manually, but I'd rather don't do it manually (for example, to avoid having to change the domain in the future)

Comment: Yes, I understand what you say. But I haven't any problem passing my values to twig (if I understood you correctly). My problem is generating the url in twig, if I put all in that way I am getting /search/value instead of /search?value=value I need the second option

Comment: No it won't equal 'value', if you use let's say `getMyValue` and that returns an integer. The the URL would be `/search/34237`, that is if `getMyValue` returned `34237` as an integer. Do you understand? It doesn't equal `value`!

Comment: Yes, I know that if I pass an entity to my twig template and I have a getter in my entity, I will can access to that value. But in my case I am not passing an entity to my twig template, it is just a string. Let's say that string is "test", so I want the following url: /search?value=test I think maybe I did not put the best values in my example

Comment: See my second edit. I have not idea why you would pass in a string? That does not make sense at all! Normally you would pass in a queried result set - which is dynamic. In other words, you do a search and you pass in the search result.

Comment: Yes, I have a form with an input and other options too, so I get the input in the controller and pass it to twig. And sorry but I think that you didn't understand me. At this moment I have urls like `/search/test` but I want urls like `/search?value=test`